# Excel Macro date prompt for current date and changes the next cell 1 day ahead

Tags: excel, vba

How would I create an macro to prompt with current date and change the next cell 1 day ahead? I have a sample of what I have so far. Let me know if I am Close.

```
Sub Change_dates()
    Dim dtDate As Date
    dtDate = InputBox("Date", , Date)
    For Each cell In Intersect(Range("B " & dblRow).Value = dtDate, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Select = cell.Offset(0, 1).Select + 1
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will prompt with current date, write to active cell, then write date + 1 to cell in the next column.

```
Sub Change_dates()
Dim dtDate As Date
dtDate = InputBox("Date", , Date)

ActiveCell.Value = dtDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = dtDate + 1

End Sub
```

This will take the date from the prompt, write it in the selected rows in the range, then put the date + 1 in the rows one column to the right from the selected range.

```
Sub Change_dates_range()
Dim dtDate As Date
dtDate = InputBox("Date", , Date)

Set SelRange = Selection

For Each b In SelRange.Rows
    b.Value = dtDate
    b.Offset(0, 1).Value = dtDate + 1
Next

End Sub
```

If you instead want each row in the range to be + 1 day the row before, then I would increment dtDate at the end of the loop before the Next statement.

Comment: How would I do this for more than one row in a cell?

Comment: If you are simply selecting a range and want to iterate over that range, replace the two ActiveCell lines with the following:

Set SelRange = Selection

For Each b In SelRange.Rows
    b.Offset(0, 1).Value = dtDate + 1  
Next

Edit: Sorry the line breaks are destroyed, I'm new to this.

Comment: Me to...Can you write the example out again please.

Comment: `Set SelRange = Selection <line break>

For Each b in SelRange.Rows <line break>
<tab> b.Offset(0, 1).Value = dtDate + 1 <line break>
Next`

That will iterate over the range and make the next row over the original date entered at the prompt + 1.

Comment: its only changing the current day next cell date...It is not changing then range for exanmple ("B25:B50") then adding the day to the following rows?  Am I missing something. If you want to edit your answer click on the edit button under your answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you're looking for:

```
Sub Change_dates()
Dim dtDate As Date
Dim rng As Range
Dim FirstRow As Integer
   dtDate = InputBox("Date", , Date)
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").Find(What:=dtDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
   FirstRow = rng.Row
Do
   rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("B:B").FindNext(After:=rng)
Loop Until rng.Row = FirstRow

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a Run time error '1004'"  Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: Huh... It works on my computer... My GUESS is because i didn't reference the sheet... Try this updated code and make sure to run it from the sheet you're looking to make these changes in...