# Prompt for current date and change the next cells for each day of the month

Tags: excel, vba

I found this, which works:
[Excel Macro date prompt for current date and changes the next cell 1 day ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976677/excel-macro-date-prompt-for-current-date-and-changes-the-next-cell-1-day-ahead?newreg=d8404835ecfd4f639a0763401b443cad)

I would like a prompt that would allow the user to input a date and then for each column to populate with that date +1 (like in the above link), but continue until the end of the month, ideally specifying that March has 31 days, June has 30, etc.

I tried:

```vb
Sub Change_dates()
Dim dtDate As Date
dtDate = InputBox("Date", , Date)

ActiveCell.Value = dtDate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = dtDate + 1

End Sub
```

and

```vb
Sub Change_dates_range()
Dim dtDate As Date
dtDate = InputBox("Date", , Date)

Set SelRange = Selection

For Each b In SelRange.Rows
    b.Value = dtDate
    b.Offset(0, 1).Value = dtDate + 1
Next

End Sub
```

Which only provided two dates. How do I make this loop until the end of the month?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```vb
Sub Change_dates_range()
    
    Dim dtDate As Date, m As Long, c As Range
    
    dtDate = InputBox("Date", , Date)
    m = Month(dtDate)
    Set c = Selection.Cells(1)
        
    Do
        c.Value = dtDate
        dtDate = dtDate + 1
        Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop While Month(dtDate) = m

End Sub
```

Comment: If this answered your question. please mark it as "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark: this helps anyone coming along later with a similar question to see there's a working solution.